# Using style.less from lesscss.org doesn't properly show changes I make to the style.less file?

Tags: wordpress, javascript, css, css-framework

I inherited a wordpress project that was initially developed by another developer and for the CSS they utilize the script from: http://lesscss.org (which so far seems to not only be overkill but horrible if the user doesn't have javascript enabled on their browser)

My guess is that it is caching but even in safari if I disable Cache, it doesn't  update with my changes.

Safari loaded with some changes, but when I made more changes it only shows the same time from the first page view. Same thing in firefox except firefox doesn't show any of the new changes. This only applies to css changes made in the style.less file. If I make any changing to the html code then every loads correctly.

I even tried appending #!watch’ to the url like the web page said, but still no luck.

Any idea on what I can do to make the changes load correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> (which so far seems to not only be overkill but horrible if the user
>   doesn't have javascript enabled on their browser)

This is not entirely true, typically LESS stylesheets compile to CSS and are served to the users are regular CSS.

I've never heard of a web application serving LESS styles and then invoking a javascript library to convert that LESS into actual CSS. That would be counter-productive.

I've never worked with Wordpress (really digging into the code base) but typically, the LESS stylesheet is compiled to CSS on *some kind of event*. In my case, a Visual Studio 2010 extension would compile the LESS into a typical .CSS file and I would use that.

So dig into the code and figure out **when the LESS is being turned into CSS**. You may find out that what you're writing in the .less file isn't even being added into the .css file you are serving.

Maybe it's not an automatic process on Wordpress and you have to manually convert the stylesheets.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Are there other implementations of LESS stylesheets aside from the link I posted above? I can't find any functionality that would cause the css to cache or anything. Here is the code in the header, which is the only reference I can find to it... I looked in all the files which contain any functionality 

`<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.less">

    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/less-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`